# How to know user is online or offline in quickblox for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, quickblox

I am storing user contact in arrContactList

```
NSArray *arrContactList =  [QBChat instance].contactList.contacts;
```

From arrContactList, how the presence status can be derived.

Also after getting presence status, if user goes online or offline, how it can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// contact has userId and presence status

```
for(QBContactListItem *contact in arrContactList) {

    BOOL isOnline = contact.isOnline;
    NSInteger userIdValue = contact.userID;

    if(isOnline) {
        NSLog(@"User %ld is online",(long)userIdValue);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"User %ld is offline",(long)userIdValue);
    }
}
```

// When a contact user goes online or offline, this method gets called

```
- (void)chatDidReceiveContactItemActivity:(NSUInteger)userID isOnline:(BOOL)isOnline status:(NSString *)status{

    // here you can check presence status using isOnline and also we get userID
    // so list of user IDs who are online can be maintained in an array
}
```